# How to modify the size of two array/dataset to be same in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have two arrays/dataset.

```
scala> data1.collect
res2: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 100.0), Array(0.7, 100.0), Array(0.8, 50.0))

scala> data2.collect
res3: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(0.25, 0.0, 0.0), Array(1.0, 125.0, 0.0), Array(0.5, 0.0, 20.0), Array(0.5, 0.0, 15.0))
```

I want that `data1` and `data2` size to be same (number of inside arrays should be same, in `data1` number of inside array is 3 and in `data2` it is 4). I want to add one `Array(0.0, 0.0)` or as many same number of `Array(0.0, 0.0)` in `data1` as it is present in `data2`.

Please tell me a way to do that.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have two dataframes with a single column containing an Array. And you want to add more rows to one of them until the number of rows are the same?

Comment: both are datasets and i want to make the number of records same.if not same add record with zero value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find out how many new rows you need to add to the `data1` dataset. Using some example data from the question:

```
val data1 = Seq(Seq(1.0, 100.0), Seq(0.7, 100.0), Seq(0.8, 50.0))
  .toDF("col1").as[Array[Double]]
val data2 = Seq(Seq(0.8, 50.0), Seq(1.0, 125.0, 0.0), Seq(0.5, 0.0, 20.0), Seq(0.5, 0.0, 15.0))
  .toDF("col1").as[Array[Double]]

val diff = data2.count() - data1.count()
```

In this case `diff` will have a value of 1.

Next, create a new datasetwith the appropriate number of rows containing only the `Array(0.0, 0.0)` that should be appended. Then add this new dataset to `data1` by using `union`:

```
val appendData = Seq.fill(diff.toInt)(Array(0.0, 0.0)).toDF("col1").as[Array[Double]]
val data3 = data1.union(appendData)
```

Result:

```
+------------+
|        col1|
+------------+
|[1.0, 100.0]|
|[0.7, 100.0]|
| [0.8, 50.0]|
|  [0.0, 0.0]|
+------------+
```